# Kubernetes on an AWS-hosted cluster (not EKS): Where does infrastructure replication logic go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, drone.io

I have a Kubernetes-orchestraded infrastructure that is served on an AWS-hosted cluster. I'd like to have routines that would allow me to spawn similar infrastructures. The difference between the original infrastructure and the newly-spawned ones would mainly be the DNS's used and the images that I would serve.

My question is: What is the most appropriate place for this similar-infrastructure-spawning code to reside: Kubernetes ? My CI/CD tool, Drone? Some other DevOps stack component of which I'm not even aware?

Comment: I have my drone use the terraform binary to deploy changes when there is a change in the infrastructure code (which we design/write in terraform src files). Terraform/infrastructure files live in its own git-repo with its own drone.yml

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever think about InfraAsCode tech.

You can directly develop your infrastructure using code like:

- Cloudformation (AWS)
- Terraform (multi provider)
- Ansible
- ...

You will then be able to configure all providers services (not only your cluster)

You will then be able to deploy it with a single command and use parameters on it.

Otherwise you can also you a tool like Kops (https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) to automate deployment of you K8s cluster.

Once you choose the right tool, you will then be able to source it using Git repository or whatever.

Comment: And also automate delivery process using runner (gitlab, jenkins, ...)